# In Debian, how to recover /usr/share/doc?

Tags: apt, package-management

On an old laptop running debian Jessie, I was doing an upgrade

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But during the process, I checked the free space with [`df`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=df&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en) and saw that soon, less than 20 seconds, there will be no more space. So I did

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/doc
```

The freed space was enough to terminate correctly the upgrade process.

Now, I want to install again all the lost documentation. How can I list all the installed packages having files in `/usr/share/doc` and repair them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apt-get --reinstall install …` to reinstall all the files in a bunch of packages. To get the list of packages that contain a specific file, use `dpkg -S`. `dpkg -S /usr/share/doc` searches for substrings of file names, so it'll find all files whose path contains `/usr/share/doc`, including a hypothetical `/usr/lib/foo/usr/share/doc/`, but that doesn't matter here.

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/doc | sed 's/:.*//' | sort -u |
xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install
```

Answer (score 1):

Every single package in Debian ships at least a symlink in `/usr/share/doc`, to provide the `copyright` file which details the package's license. So you'll pretty much need to reinstall everything!

A package's files are listed in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/package.list` (replacing `package` as appropriate); the following will reinstall affected packages:

```
grep -l /usr/share/doc /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list |
sed 'sX.*/XXg;s/\.list$//g' |
sudo xargs apt-get --reinstall install
```